# Removing Modal backdrop on a single Modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single modal that is receiving styling from the global site.css due to having several other modals within partials, and keeping with DRY I want to alter only this one by removing the Modal Fade In class. Currently, my jQuery is ignoring this.

jQuery

```
if (modal.hasId('#modalBanner')) {
        $('.modal fade in').removeClass('modal fade in ');
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" id="modalBanner" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-FullWidth">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `$('#modalBanner').removeClass('modal fade in ');` ?, can I see your HTML with this particular modal?.

Comment: This (.modal fade in) is not a class so check again as to its name. you cant have spaces like that. This would be ok (.modal-fade-in) or (.modal,  .fade-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(".modal.fade.in")
```

Use that as your selector, it says a selector with a class of 'modal' 'fade' and 'in'

Comment: if I use this method, would I need to drop the RemoveClass Selector and make it just Remove?

Comment: Found where the issue was coming from, and yours worked.

Comment: Sweet! So yeah you would still want the removeClass() as you had it

`$(".modal.fade.in").removeClass("modal fade in");`

Although I think just removing the "in" class would hide the modal as well.

Comment: yes, that was part of the issue, the other part was that I had a positioning issue that was adding a second layer, when I removed that, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code in your jquery to remove modal backdrop:

```
$('.modal').remove();
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').removeClass( "modal-open" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright.

```
$('#modalBanner').removeClass('modal fade in');
```

Should do the trick.

You can access the element by ID then, just remove the classes you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response, though neither of these seems to have resolved the issue